# Install TWS on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, interactive-brokers

Hello everyone I am trying to install IB api software but I am facing a problem and I don't know what is !!

**Here the installation process:**

- Download TWS from https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=16040
- chmod u+x tws-latest-linux-x64.sh
- ./tws-latest-linux-x64.sh

**Errors faced:**

```
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
Downloading JRE with wget ...
--2017-11-11 13:26:12--  https://download2.interactivebrokers.com/installers/jres/linux-x64-1.8.0_152.tar.gz
Resolving download2.interactivebrokers.com (download2.interactivebrokers.com)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘download2.interactivebrokers.com’
Unpacking JRE ...

gzip: jre.tar.gz: unexpected end of file
tar: ../jre.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Starting Installer ...
./tws-latest-linux-x64.sh: 613: ./tws-latest-linux-x64.sh: /home/user1/Downloads/tws-latest-linux-x64.sh.8674.dir/jre/bin/java: not found
```

Any help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a firewall? Set your proxy

export https_proxy=proxy:port
export http_proxy=proxy:port

Else just install jvm manually to fulfill that requirement.

You can also add the proxy to the wget command too.